# npm run install with --prefix creates 'etc' folder

Tags: npm, node-modules

In package.json (let's say it's defined in *Scripts* folder) I have script defined like this:

```
"scripts": {
   "install:prod": "npm i"
}
```

If i run this script from *Scripts* folder everything is correct, only node_modules is created . But when I run script from parent folder i receive strange output. 
For example when I'm running:

```
npm run install:prod --prefix ./WebApp/Scripts
```

*etc* folder and many files command from node_modules are put inside *Scripts* folder

```
    Mode    Length Name
    d-----         etc
    d-----         node_modules
    d-----         src
    ------     123 .babelrc
    -a----     321 acorn
    -a----     198 acorn.cmd
    -a----     337 ansi-html
    -a----     214 ansi-html.cmd
    -a----     323 atob
    -a----     200 atob.cmd
    -a----     329 browserslist
    -a----     206 browserslist.cmd
    -a----     325 cssesc
    ... and much more
```

Is it desired behaviour? How can i build node_modules from parent folder without *etc* and other unnecessary (for me) files, just like running normal npm install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Production building script was running on another server so all npm scripts were blocked. After changing network path to physical (command: `pushd \\serverpath`) we were able to change directory and run npm freely. `cd Scripts && npm run install` did the work.